# What is wrong with the $f$ symbol?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols, amsmath

I came across some spacing glitches when I use the *f* symbol (I'm not having similar weirdness with most other symbols).  Here's a very simple MWE to show the issue:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}
\newcommand*{\kp}[1]{\mskip+#1mu}
\newcommand*{\kn}[1]{\mskip-#1mu}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        \frac{d f}{d r} = \frac{d\kp1 f}{d\kp1 r} = \frac{d\kp1 \kn2 f}{d\kp1 r}.
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

The case **A** is too tight for my taste.  I frequently add some small space between symbols to "kern" my equations.  Adding a simple 1/3 of a small space (`\,`) between *d* and *f* gives an output space that is too large, while it's not the case with other symbols (case **B**).  Then adding 1/3 and removing 2/3 gives a nice output (case **C**).  What is going on here?  How can I use the *f* symbol without having to add some kerning each time with it?

Comment: My guess is the `\mskip` interferes with the natural kerning mechanism built into the font.  The fact that `\kp0` changes the result seems to indicate this,

Comment: Just compare `df` and `d{}f` to get an idea of what is going on.

Comment: I was just about to say what @HenriMenke said

Comment: If you want a little space around the differential, consider maybe something like `\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{d\!}}`.

Comment: For differentials in particular you may also be interested in the `diffcoeff` package on CTAN.

Comment: @HenriMenke That's wrong, sorry. Try `\diff(x+y)`

Comment: @chsk I have see now your comment. If you prefer I delete my answer. Excuse me.

Comment: By all means, please keep your answer. Why would you delete it?

Comment: @chsk Hi, I have not noticed your comment for the missing ping. Sometimes when I create the code I not see the comments...and you have cited the same package of my answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano that's fine. The whole point of the site is to provide useful answers, is it not? And yours definitely is.

Comment: @chsk Yes of course...but if I have put my previous comment there was a reason: :-)...old remembers into this community.

Answer (score 20):

The `cmmi10` font (and this is followed by `lmmi10`) has specifically a kerning between `d` and `f`:

```
(CHARACTER C d
   (CHARWD R 0.520488)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   (COMMENT
      (KRN C Y R 0.055555)
      (KRN C Z R -0.055555)
      (KRN C j R -0.111112)
      (KRN C f R -0.166667)
      (KRN O 177 R 0.166672)
      )
   )
```

exactly in order to avoid the unsightly hole that you seem to like.

Here's my suggestions: I'd use `\standarddiff`, you might prefer `\chamdiff` (rename your choice to `\diff` or whatever you like).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fixcmex} % don't forget with lmodern

\newcommand{\standarddiff}{\mathop{}\!d}
\newcommand{\chamdiff}{\mathop{}\!d\/}

\begin{document}

$\standarddiff f \quad \standarddiff j \quad \standarddiff r$

$\chamdiff f \quad \chamdiff j \quad \chamdiff r$

$d\mkern1mu f$ $d\mkern-1mu f$

\end{document}
```

Either no kerning (1mu is not good, in my opinion), or the standard.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You might be interested in the  `esdiff` package, which takes care of the spacing problem, and simplifies the typing of Leibniz notation, for both ordinary and partial derivatives. By default the differential symbol is in roman, but you have the `[italic]` option at loading time.

Unrelated: needless to load `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`, which is an extension of the former.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[italic]{esdiff}

\begin{document}

    \[ \diff{f}{r}, \quad \diff[2]{f}{r}, \qquad \diffp{h}{{x^2}{y}}. \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You could to use also `diffcoeff` package like this minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\begin{document}
\[\diff[1]fr=\diff{\onemu f}{r}=\diff {\nilmu f}{\onemu r}\]
\end{document}
```

where the correct spacing are defined from the commands:

`\negmu` insert spacing of `−1 mu`

`\nilmu` insert spacing of `0 mu`

`\onemu` insert spacing of `1 mu`

`\twomu` insert spacing of `2 mu`

See the guide to the pag. 7/32.

[image]